# How can I join two results

Tags: sql, postgresql, pg

I have 3 tables purchase, air_transfers and sea_transfers.
I have made the example code in [db fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=513024ab1ad1bb5433ce52a769452e40). My problem is on 6th paragraph where I don't have any sea transfers, I get null as id and thats because I'm using id from sea transfers. What should I do to fix this?

purchase table:

```
CREATE TABLE purchase
(
id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
date DATE NOT NULL
)
```

air transfer table:

```
CREATE TABLE air_transfers
(
id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
purchase_id INTEGER NOT NULL REFERENCES purchase(id),
units INTEGER NOT NULL
)
```

sea transfers table:

```
CREATE TABLE sea_transfers
(
id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
purchase_id INTEGER NOT NULL REFERENCES purchase(id),
units INTEGER NOT NULL
)
```

my outer join:

```
WITH sea_transfers AS (
SELECT purchase_id, SUM(units) AS units
FROM sea_transfers
GROUP BY purchase_id
),
air_transfers AS (
SELECT purchase_id, SUM(units) AS units
FROM air_transfers
GROUP BY purchase_id
)
SELECT st.purchase_id, (COALESCE(st.units,0) + COALESCE(at.units,0)) AS units
FROM sea_transfers AS st
FULL OUTER JOIN air_transfers AS at
ON st.purchase_id = at.purchase_id
```

if my sea transfers is empty I get this result:

[image]

Comment: You should probably include your code in the question, in case that website goes down in the future, the question will still be meaningful.

Comment: @Zakaria ok thanks I'll do it now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for `UNION ALL` instead of `FULL OUTER JOIN`, because `UNION ALL` will combine two results `air_transfers` and `sea_transfers` tables, you will get all `purchase_id` and `units` values from two tables.

```
SELECT  purchase_id, SUM(units) AS units
FROM (
   SELECT purchase_id,units FROM air_transfers
   UNION ALL
   SELECT purchase_id,units FROM sea_transfers
) t1
GROUP BY purchase_id
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do

```
SELECT COALESCE(st.purchase_id, at.purchase_id) as purchase_id
```

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=7d46e6487a574548f71b9a72efbe19e5)

#### 3rd party edit

From [sqlitetutorial.net](https://www.sqlitetutorial.net/sqlite-functions/sqlite-coalesce/):

> The COALESCE function accepts two or more arguments and returns the
> first non-null argument. The following illustrates the syntax of the
> COALESCE function:

```
SELECT COALESCE(10,20); -- return 10
SELECT COALESCE(NULL,20,10); -- returns 20
```

From the [official sqlite docs](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_corefunc.html#coalesce)

> **coalesce(X,Y,...)**
>
> The coalesce() function returns a copy of its first non-NULL argument, or > NULL if all arguments are NULL. Coalesce() must have at least 2 arguments.